# can't remove the padding under menu items bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I can't seem to get the padding inside the menu to be removed or changed. I don't want my navbar to be so chunky and large. I got the top padding removed but the bottom isn't working.

[image]

this is the code that got the top to the right size (border around menu is to show the emphasis on the problem)

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-bottom: 0px; /*<-- does not set the bottom to 0px*/
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Manvaril/v97e0u0w/

Comment: could you show your html elements also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would debug this problem:

Start with inspecting the empty space:

[image]

I see that the menu shouldn't be 48 pixels tall.  Now I inspect the *Home* link:

[image]

So I'd imagine it should be smaller than 48 but larger than 20.  Now I work my way back until I find the element that's causing it to be to large:

[image]

Now inspect the element styles and find the source:

[image]

So it looks like in `navbar.less` the following code exists:

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

All you need to do is override that globally or specifically as needed in a stylesheet after bootstrap:

```
// globally
.navbar {
  min-height: 10px;  // or whatever value
}

// specifically (as best as I can based on your code)
.rgo_wrapper .navbar {
  min-height: 10px;  // or whatever value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a` CSS selector does not select the `navbar-brand` element in your `nav-bar`. Therefore you can modify it to `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-default .navbar-brand`. There is a fixed height to `navbar-brand` anchor element. So add the following CSS rule as well.

`.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    height: 20px; // your desired height
}`

Comment: This didn't work here is a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Manvaril/v97e0u0w/

Comment: Add this to your jsFiddle, this worked for me.
`.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-default .navbar-brand{
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar {
    min-height: 20px;
}`

Comment: Add following to your jsFiddle. This worked for me,

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-default .navbar-brand{
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar {
    min-height: 20px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Its because the "**navbar**" class is having **min-height** of 50px. its in "bootstrap.less" file line number 15
remove min-height:50px from .navbar class.
or add **min-height:0;** on your "**navbar-default**" class after line 45 in your css.

```
.navbar-default {
    min-height:0;
```

}